# Code box line width survey

Tags: discussion

For the purpose of understanding what other users see, and to provide a record of the current SE Beta formatting, I would like to conduct a survey of the line width of the code boxes that users see.

Please use a "ruler" like this one to determine how many characters your system displays *before* the horizontal scroll bar appears, then post *the ruler* as an answer.

```
         1         2         3         4         5         6         7         8
123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901
```

If an answer already exists with that size of ruler, please *vote for that answer* instead.

Optionally edit the answer to include a description of your browser or device in a bulleted list or place it in a comment below the answer.

**Please only post one "ruler" in each answer, and please refrain from making commentary in the body of the answer (use comments).  This way it is clear what each vote given to each answer represents.**

Comment: We should upvote the answers to death. They are all right!

Comment: This depends on the zoom factor as well.

Comment: @Szabolcs yes, that is why I specifically included it in my own (sample) answer.

Comment: But this really is confusing me now. Does this mean if I write something and the line is wide for me, and no wrapping, but then for another person on another system, it can appear wrapped and the slider will show up for them?? I do not want this. I do not like to have to scroll to see the full code. If so, then how does not make sure the code/answer they put does not wrap on any other system? Is there a minimum width to use and how to check for it while writing?

Comment: FWIW: on a mobile phone, I don't see a horizontal scroll; instead, the code gets broken in odd places prolly dictated by the small screen size.

Answer (score 11):

```
         1         2         3         4         5         6         7         8         9  
12345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012
```

- This is using Chrome on a 13.3 inch macbook.
- Safari 5.1.9 on OS X 10.6.8 at actual size (100% zoom).  Jun 16 at 9:35 -- m_goldberg
- windows 7, firefox, 100% (Nasser)

Comment: Also Chrome on Win7 at 100% zoom

Comment: Chrome on Mac and Linux.

Comment: And Chrome on Win8 just to complete the set.  Should note that Chrome consistently displays the 93rd character without clipping on Mac/Windows, but *also* displays a scrollbar.

Answer (score 10):

```
         1         2         3         4         5         6         7         8         9   
123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123
```

- Opera 12.00 on Windows 7 at 100% zoom
- Pale Moon 26.3.3 on Windows 10 at 100% zoom
- Firefox 47.0 on Windows 7 at 100% zoom

Comment: Firefox 13 on WinXP, Consolas installed.

Comment: Firefox 13 on Windows 7 at 100% (default) zoom (ClearType on)

Comment: @Mr.Wizard I upvoted this and deleted mine

Comment: Iceweasel 3.5.16 (Debian-branded version of Firefox) on Linux, default (100%) zoom.

Answer (score 6):

```
         1         2         3         4         5         6         7         8         9
123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890
```

- Firefox 12.0 under MacOS 10.6.8 on 15" Macbook Pro

Comment: Firefox 21 Windows 7, 15.6" notebook, 1920x1080 screen.

Comment: Firefox 22 MacOS 10.8.6 on 15" Macbook Pro with Retina display. Kinda disappointed that it didn't change. :P

Answer (score 2):

```
         1         2         3         4         5         6         7         8  
12345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123
```

- Chrome 51 on Ubuntu 15.10 at 100% zoom.

Comment: Significantly shorter than all the other existing answers, for whatever reason.

Comment: Thank you for participating in my survey.

Answer (score 1):

```
         1         2         3         4         5         6         7         8         9         
123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789
```

- Firefox 13, Windows 7, ClearType on: when using **130% or greater Full Page Zoom**
- Firefox 22, Windows 7, ClearType on: when using **135% Full Page Zoom**

Answer (score 1):

```
         1         2         3         4         5         6         7         8         9         0
1234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456
```

Opera 12.00 on Windows 7 at 130% zoom (but the top and bottom lines of the ruler are no longer lined up).

Comment: Thanks.  Do you know why the alignment goes off with those settings?  With FF I can zoom to 200% and my answer (99) is still valid and aligned.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Sorry, I don't know. It seems to be related to resizing the spaces in the top line differently to other characters--perhaps tracking and/or kerning are enabled for fonts over a certain size and some characters are hinted while others are not, or not correctly. (This is Consolas, the hinting for which you can readily find complaints about via Google.)

Answer (score 1):

```
         1         2         3         4         5         6         7         8         9         0
12345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901
```

- Firefox 23, Windows 7, 100% zoom

Comment: If I zoom out( 80-90 %) or in scroll-bars pops up but not in 100%

Answer (score 0):

My iPad doesn't display scrollbars in code windows, but it scrolls like you requested in your recent drag box question.

```
         1         2         3         4         5         6         7         8         9         
1234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901
```

Comment: You have some extra spaces after the `9` of the first line, which make a difference in scrolling.