# Does the code block on Mathematica.SE has a fixed width on all systems?

Tags: discussion

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Code box line width survey](https://mathematica.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/465/code-box-line-width-survey)

I'm interested in how consistent the code blocks look on different systems and with different browsers. What I try to find out is whether or not our site has a fixed width for the code block.

After the nice working [Image Uploader](https://mathematica.meta.stackexchange.com/a/32/187) for our site, a consistent [Code Formatter Palette](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/2810/187) could be a next step. We could maximize the line-length (and make the number of code lines smaller) when we would know, whether the appearance is consistent on different systems.

Here on this Ubuntu Linux system, I can type exactly **92** characters in one line, before I get an ugly scroll-bar below the code block.

```
12345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012
```

This width changes of course when I scale the fontsize in my browser. It would be nice, if people could check whether they see the code-block without space at the right side and without scroll-bar. If yes, vote this question up, if no you could find out your exact width and make an answer. If your width has already an answer, just vote the answer up.

With such a code formatting palette you could insert beautiful code with one click. Here an example

```
findLsts3[lst_,len_Integer?Positive,maxZeros_,n:_Integer|All:All]:=
  Module[{zeroLst,rangeLst,startLst},    
    zeroLst=Flatten[Position[lst,0|0.`|Null]];
    If[
      Length[zeroLst]<=maxZeros,
      startLst=Range[Length[lst]-len+1],
      (* else *)      
      rangeLst=
        Transpose[
          {            
            Prepend[Drop[zeroLst+1,-maxZeros],1],
            Append[Drop[zeroLst-len,maxZeros],Length[lst]-len+1]
          }
        ];
      startLst=
        Flatten[
          Apply[Range,List@@Interval@@Select[rangeLst,#1[[2]]-#1[[1]]>=0&],{1}],1
        ]
    ];
    ({lst[[#1;;#1+len-1]],#1}&)/@Sort[RandomSample[startLst,n]]
  ]
```

Comment: So... the same as [this](http://meta.mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/465/5)?

Comment: Yep. I didn't search the meta before posting because I thought no one would have asked such a question before. Sorry, that was a waste of time.

Comment: By the way, I have such a palette in my nearest plans. The only reason why I did not roll it out yet is that the code formatter is still full of bugs, and also needs a serious refactoring. Alas, I was under a heavy load at work in the last 3-4 months, but that should change soon. Bugs are more immediately important, but without the refactoring the formatter may soon become a mess, and besides, people generally like different formatting styles. I want to implement a DSL on top of the formatter,so that people can write scripts in it to instruct the formatter to format in a specific style.