# Mathematica.Stackexchange Themes - Show your styles!

Tags: discussion, design, site-tools

Mathematica.Stackexchange only has one default theme and the [preferences setting options](https://mathematica.meta.stackexchange.com/users/preferences) are very limited. However, as any website, its appearance can be modified by altering its CSS in the browser.

What themes do you use to change the appearance of Mathematica.Stackexchange?

Answer (score 5):

### Editor width and Blockquotes

There are two annoying features of the default theme. The major one is the incorrect line breaks for code blocks in the editor, which makes editing multiline code blocks to fit into the site without horizontal scroll bars way too cumbersome. The minor one is the nonexistence of [a proper output style](https://mathematica.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1508/18476) and a rather disgusting color for blockquotes.

I created a style and made it available as [MathematicaStackexchange_Default-Customization](https://userstyles.org/styles/132017/mathematicastackexchange-default-customization) (for Firefox and Pale Moon) on https://userstyles.org that removes these.

The width of the editor is extended to make line breaks within code blocks to be matching in the editor and the post, when a vertical scroll bar is present in the editor.
Blockquotes appear to be output-citing by having the same background-color as code and by indenting them. Their top and bottom padding is reduced, while their total width is the same as the default.

Furthermore there is [MathematicaStackexchange_Chrome-Customization](https://userstyles.org/styles/132031/mathematicastackexchange-chrome-customization) for Chrome, that additionally increases the with of posts a little bit, to make the code box line width match the [most common one](https://mathematica.meta.stackexchange.com/a/468/18476).

---

**Example with the style applied:**
[image: myStyle]

---

**Example without the style applied:**
[image: defaultStyle]

Answer (score 5):

I took the least resistance path. I've found [StylishThemes/StackOverflow-Dark](https://github.com/StylishThemes/StackOverflow-Dark), installed [Stylish](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/stylish/fjnbnpbmkenffdnngjfgmeleoegfcffe) and added mma.se path in options:

> ^https?://((chat|meta).)?mathematica.stackexchange.com.*

[image]

Isn't perfect but good enough.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 4):

### Dark Theme

The default theme is nice during the day, but after sun set, in low light conditions, or a long day in front of the screen it feels very bright. Therefore I created a dark theme that's much easier on my eyes, especially when I just want to read some posts or the chat.
It is available as [MathematicaStackexchange_DarkStyle](https://userstyles.org/styles/132018/mathematicastackexchange-darkstyle) on https://userstyles.org.

---

**Questions preview:**
[image: MainSite]

---

**Chat preview**
[image: Chat]

---

This theme grew incrementally by adding new instructions whenever I encountered something that did not yet look nice. Therefore, there are probably parts of the site that don't fit into this theme. There might also be some inconsistencies and bad css and design styles. I even left some of the shadow boxes that are part of the default theme in this style, because I found them so ridiculous that they are almost funny.